# Preventing null under certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to express a conditional validation on an insert or update to a table (SQL Server 2008 R2) that says column A cannot be null if column B is equal to 12,13 or 14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement this with a table level [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_YourCheck 
CHECK(ColumnA IS NOT NULL OR ColumnB NOT IN (12, 13, 14))
```

Comment: Already upvoted, but probably worth adding example code based on the specific question.

Comment: Odd...when I try this I get the error The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint CK_YourCheck...how does the statement conflict with a constraint that does not exist. And in case you are wondering, I did double check the data in place now does not violate the constraint.

Comment: Try changing it to `ALTER TABLE YourTable WITH NOCHECK...`

Comment: @keithwarren7 - no, it doesn't. This is *exactly* what the error is telling you - that trying to apply the check constraint has found rows in violation of it. There *may* be issues if `ColumnB` is nullable (and contains nulls) ...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - which effectively makes it documentation about your hopes and dreams of what the DB should contain, rather than an actual constraint. Why bother?

Comment: If it worked with the `NOCHECK`, the issue before was like the error message was suggesting, and the data in your table was violating the constraint.  You should probably drop the constraint, clean up the data, and then try creating it again without the `NOCHECK`.

Comment: Are you aware of some circumstance where adding the constraint "as is" fails with a constraint violation message, and adding it with `NOCHECK` *also* gets the same message? If so, I'd like details. If not, adding it with `NOCHECK` adds no value, and may suggest to the OP that they've solved their problem (when they haven't).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right - I was attempting to show Keith that if the constraint could be created successfully if the existing data was ignored, that the failure before had to be caused by the data in his table.  He had already stated that it wasn't the data, so showing him that it WAS the data seemed more productive at the time... but an explanation of why I was asking him to try that would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this using a [Check Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

Something like this?

```
ADD CONSTRAINT check validCHECK ( 
       ((B BETWEEN 12 and 14) AND A IS NOT NULL) 
        OR B NOT BETWEEN 12 and 14 
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

In first-order logic, this is known as implication:

```
IF x THEN y
```

Applying the implcation law, the above can be transformed to this:

```
( NOT ( x ) ) OR y
```

Substituting your expressions:

```
IF column B is equal to 12,13 or 14 THEN A cannot be null
```

Applying the implcation law:

```
( NOT ( column B is equal to 12,13 or 14 ) ) OR A cannot be null
```

Substituting SQL expressions:

```
( NOT ( B IN (12, 13, 14) ) ) OR ( NOT ( A IS NULL ) )
```

Applying De Morgan's laws:

```
( NOT x ) OR ( NOT y ) is equivlent to NOT ( x AND y )
```

Hence:

```
NOT ( B IN (12, 13, 14) AND A IS NULL )
```

SQL DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD 
   CONSTRAINT your_rule
      CHECK ( NOT ( B IN (12, 13, 14) AND A IS NULL ) );
```